# Generic type in typeorm and nestjs

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to make a base service that will be extendable. The service takes a generic type which will be the Entity type that typeorm uses, that type must have some props and therefore I want it to extend an interface that has those props:

```
import { getManager, FindConditions, Repository } from "typeorm";
import { UserInterface } from "./user.interface";

export abstract class UserService<User extends UserInterface> {
  constructor(
    private readonly User: new () => User,
    protected readonly userRepository: Repository<User>,
  ) {}

  async findAll(): Promise<User[]> {
    return await this.userRepository.find();
  }

  abstract async findOnePopulated(where: FindConditions<User>): Promise<User>;

  async findOneById(id: number): Promise<User> {
    return await this.findOnePopulated({ id });
  }

  async updateUser(userId: number): Promise<User> {
    const em = getManager();
    const user = await this.userRepository.findOne(userId);

    await em.update(this.User, userId, user);
    return user;
  }
}
```

I get a type error on this call `findOnePopulated({ id })`

```
[ts] Argument of type '{ id: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type
'FindConditions<User>'. [2345]
```

and this `em.update(this.User, userId, user)` is also showing a type error:

```
[ts]
Argument of type 'User' is not assignable to parameter of type 'QueryDeepPartialEntity<User>'.
  Type 'UserInterface' is not assignable to type 'QueryDeepPartialEntity<User>'. [2345]
```

It seems to not show any errors if I switch all `User` to `UserInterface` instead, is it something wrong with using the syntax `<User extends UserInterface>`?

I just want to make sure that the generic User type at least has the props in UserInterface.

Here is my UserInterface:

```
import { BaseEntity } from "typeorm";

export interface UserInterface extends BaseEntity {
  id: number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while to work it out but I'm guessing your `UserInterface` is the cause of these problems. Do you not have an entity called User? Does `UserInterface` have a key `id` with type `number`? Have you declared that the `UserInterface` is an `Entity`? If you could supply your `UserInterface` I'll take another look but my guess is because it's not an entity `@Entity()` and therefore not registered with typeorm's entity manager etc

Comment: I updated the question with the UserInterface. I don't think that one is able to use the @Entity annotation with and interface, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What does BaseEntity look like? I'm guessing it's because `QueryDeepPartialEntity` requires a type Entity to be passed in. You could try `UserInterface extends Partial<Entity>`? But I don't think that's a good idea tbh

Comment: BaseEntity is from typeorm `import { BaseEntity } from "typeorm";`

Comment: Sorry, yea missed that... I'll have a think. If I can think of anything I'll let you know